# Wordpress widget title link

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, widget

I need to create a link for a specific widget title in Wordpress and I am having some issues with this!

I have a `class-wp-widget-pages.php` with this specific code in it:

```
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? 
    __( 'Pages' ) : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
```

In the child theme, how exactly should the code look like in the newly created `class-wp-widget-pages.php` file in order to add the link functionality?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format the filename using backticks. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit your question and include any additional details necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!